# Legend with matplot

Tags: r, matplotlib, legend

rOU is a matrix of 3 columns and 250 rows and the following graph

matplot(rOU,type="l", ylim=range(rOU), col=c("black","green","red")

How can i write the legend in R for each columns of rOU?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

some reproducible data

```
set.seed(1234)
rOU = matrix(rnorm(3*250,0,1),ncol=3),dimnames = list(rep("",250),LETTERS[1:3]))
```

Then plot the data

```
matplot(rOU,type="l", ylim=range(rOU), col=c("black","green","red"), lty = 1:3, pwd = 1)
```

If you want to add it the area of the plot you can simply do:

```
legend('right',legend = colnames(rOU), col = c('black','green','red'), lty = 1:3, lwd = 1 )
```

But probably you don't want the legend to overlay the plot, so what you can do is to modify the margins of the plot to make space for the legend aside of it:

```
par(mar=c(5,5,2,6))
matplot(rOU,type="l", ylim=range(rOU), col=c("black","green","red"))
legend(280,1,legend = colnames(rOU), col = c('black','green','red'), lty = 1:3, lwd = 1 , xpd = T )
```